# Getting a json object in php

Tags: php, json, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm doing GeoRef application. This is my index.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ign.gob.ar/argenmap/argenmap.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    url: 'getcoord.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(){
            alert("ERROR");
        },
    success: function(res) {
        var ico;
            ico='Icon.png';
        var marcador;
$('#mapa').argenmap();
$('#mapa').centro(-34.597907,-58.385557)
$('#mapa').zoom(4);
    $('#mapa').capaBase('satellite');
for(var i=0;i<res.length;i++)
        { 
    marcador=[{lat: res[i].latitud, lng:res[i].longitud,icono:ico}];
    $('#mapa').argenmap().agregarMarcadores(marcador);
        }
} });});
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

And this is my getcoord.php file:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
require("db.inc");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM datos_mapa";
$res = buscar($sql);
$arry=array();
foreach ($res as $r)
    {
    $arr = array('longitud' => $r['longitud'],'latitud' => $r['latitud']);
    array_push($arry,$arr);
}
echo json_encode($arry);
?>
```

My problem is that, when I run getcoord.php using json_encode($arry), I see the information I want but, it doesn´t return to index.php. I´ve tried:

1. Using json in dataType. Gives me a Json Object but with Object in each field instead of latitude and longitude.
2. Using jsonp in dataType. Results an error.
3. Using text in dataType. I get the information I want, but as a string not as an Object.
4. Replacing echo json_encode($arry) with:

> a) json_encode($arry);
>   b) print_r(json_encode($arry));
>   c) echo $_GET['receive'].'('.json_encode($arry).');';

But getting the same error.
Why I´m not getting the information in the format I want?

---

I was trying this code at work where apache is configured and didn´t work (keeps getting error when using dataType: 'json'). In my personal computer, using xampp, it works. So I think the code is right. Is there anything else I should configure?

Comment: What do you get from `console.log(res);` in your success handler?

Comment: Also, `echo $arry;` is probably causing an issue if you are capturing the request with AJAX.

Comment: I am not sure how much data is in `$res` but you can simply do `$arry[] = $r;` in the `foreach()` loop. Or just don't do the `foreach()` loop and simply `json_encode(buscar($sql));`

Comment: console.log(res); returns undefined.<br/>
Sorry, echo $arry; is an error, should be the option d) of number4<br/>
json_encode(buscar($sql)); gives me the same error.